# impossible to leave 20.10 Gorilla

Tags: shutdown, 20.10, compaq, kubuntu-netbook

I cannot shut down nor reboot nor logout of current session.

```
Application: ksmserver-logout-greeter (ksmserver-logout-greeter), signal: Segmentation fault

Application: ksmserver-logout-greeter (ksmserver-logout-greeter), signal: Segmentation fault

[KCrash Handler]
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007fe964af5d0b in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/r300_dri.so
#6  0x00007fe964677fa4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/r300_dri.so
#7  0x00007fe964679244 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/r300_dri.so
#8  0x00007fe96465aa12 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/r300_dri.so
#9  0x00007fe964af43d7 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/r300_dri.so
#10 0x00007fe965de6bf3 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0
#11 0x00007fe965dd5539 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0
#12 0x00007fe96707ed5d in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so
#13 0x00007fe96d32ad5f in QOpenGLContext::destroy() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#14 0x00007fe96d32b00b in QOpenGLContext::~QOpenGLContext() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#15 0x00007fe967080e50 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so
#16 0x00007fe96708145d in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so
#17 0x00007fe96e68ccfd in QSGRenderLoop::instance() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#18 0x00007fe96e70c56d in QQuickWindowPrivate::init(QQuickWindow*, QQuickRenderControl*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#19 0x00007fe96ee8ae14 in KQuickAddons::QuickViewSharedEngine::QuickViewSharedEngine(QWindow*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5QuickAddons.so.5
#20 0x000055c85a4c9b78 in ?? ()
#21 0x000055c85a4c87af in ?? ()
#22 0x000055c85a4c8a9f in ?? ()
#23 0x000055c85a4cb7bd in ?? ()
#24 0x00007fe96d8872d9 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5
#25 0x00007fe96d88c77c in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5
#26 0x00007fe96d88d033 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5
#27 0x00007fe96d88feec in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5
#28 0x00007fe96cf44651 in QObject::event(QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#29 0x00007fe96da61013 in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#30 0x00007fe96cf181ca in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#31 0x00007fe96cf1abc1 in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int, QThreadData*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#32 0x00007fe96cf701c7 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#33 0x00007fe96af914db in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#34 0x00007fe96af91788 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#35 0x00007fe96af91853 in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#36 0x00007fe96cf6f843 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#37 0x00007fe96cf16a4b in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#38 0x00007fe96cf1efc6 in QCoreApplication::exec() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#39 0x000055c85a4c777e in ?? ()
#40 0x00007fe96c8cacb2 in __libc_start_main (main=0x55c85a4c7520, argc=1, argv=0x7ffefe9e3828, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7ffefe9e3818) at ../csu/libc-start.c:314
#41 0x000055c85a4c789e in _start ()
[Inferior 1 (process 54933) detached]
```

Comment: Press Alt+SysRq and S,U,B sequentially. The system should reboot.

Comment: Besides that: please file a bugreport against `ksmserver-logout-greeter` so they can squash it.

Answer (score 0):

Also using the halt command in terminal logged in as root or sudo'ing:

```
$ sudo halt
```